# Adding formcontrol,formgrops and formarray to duplicated html angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-forms, formgroups

I am doing an **add** form for that I need the **formcontrol**,**formgroup** setup for all these values entered in the ts. Its normal stuff maybe. But here I have it very different. I have a **add** button which duplicates the set of forms in the html. I am finding it difficult to write formgroup logic and validators in the ts for it.
Kindly help if u know(You can atleast tell me how to set up the formcontrol names ang bring it on to ts)

Note: Pls comment below if my question was unclear.

My stackblitz link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g8cty1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: What are the validators required and where you are stuck currently?

Comment: Value name and age are(all formfields) the validators required

Comment: You can atleast tell me how to set up the formcontrol names ang bring it on to ts @VimalPatel

Comment: give me some time, will provide a code sample.

Comment: okay But make sure the exissting functionality is also working.That the challenge I am facing @VimalPatel

Comment: What is the existing functionality?

Comment: When the sum of values I give in the value formfield exceeds the total value given above error message occurs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225389/discussion-between-leno-and-vimal-patel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare your FormGroup like below.

```
myForm = new FormArray([]);
addRow() {
    const group = new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
      value: new FormControl("", [Validators.required])
    });
    this.myForm.push(group);
}
```

and invoke this function whenever user click on Add button.
In Template to show the form. Loop through FormControl and bind it like below.

```
<div *ngFor="let form of myForm.controls;">
    <ng-container [formGroup]="form">
      <div>
        <label>Name</label
        ><input type="text" required formControlName="firstName" />
      </div>
      <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="isInValidFormControl(form,'firstName')">
        Name is required
      </span>
      <div>
        <label>Value</label><input type="text" formControlName="value" />
      </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Your validation with respect to total will be like below.

```
isValidTotal() {
    var values = this.myForm.controls.map((x) =>
      x ? Number(x.value.value) : 0
    );
    let sumTotal = values.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    return sumTotal <= this.total;
}
```

And you can call this from template like this.

```
  <button (click)="addRow()" [disabled]="!isValidTotal()">Add</button>
  <button (click)="submit()" [disabled]="!isValidTotal()">Submit</button>
  <div *ngIf="!isValidTotal()">
    <p>{{errorMessage}}</p>
  </div>
```

Working sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/formarraydynamic-rqdhc?file=/src/app/app.component.html

Comment: I have solved it in a different way bro. Anyway thanks @vimal

Comment: Please share your solution as well.

Comment: Sure I have posted a question a difficult one can u check it out bro